# How to make this jquery UI code compatible with jQuery UI 1.7.2 and jQuery 1.3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, refactoring

How to make this jquery UI code compatible with jQuery UI 1.7.2 and jQuery 1.3.2?

http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/NTeXV/2/

In a old project where jquery 1.3.2 is being used heavily so i can't change that and I want to style some checkboxes like this I made this by reading documentation on jquery ui website the later I found that it only works with jQuery 1.4.4 or greater and jQuery UI 1.8.7+ see here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/GUwjK/

but I want to make it work with jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.2

```
$(function() {
        $( "#check1, #check2" ).button();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button this feature was only created in version 1.8 - so you can't. The code just doesn't exist in older versions.

You could write it yourself of course, or try to strip out the parts you need and copy them.